CSS with multiple class definition
I want to apply some styles to only the "text child" div element
<div class="text">I'm a div with thin text!</div>
<div class="text">I'm a div with thin text and a child div!
   <div class="text child">I'm a smaller child div with extra bold text.</div>
</div>

and I have the following style declared for all .div.text elements
div.text {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;  
}

I tried using class selector for the text child element clearly .child should be applied to the text child element. But there is no change at all. Why?
.child {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
}


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

div.text has higher specificity than .child. Try div.text.child

or just .text.child

https://polypane.app/css-specificity-calculator/#selector= "A single value in a higher level is more important than all levels below it. For example, you can have a 1000 class names, and a selector with a single ID would still be more specific."

The issue is likely due to CSS specificity. When multiple CSS rules apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity or the one that is declared later in the CSS file will take precedence.
In your case, the div.text overrides the rule for .child because it has a higher specificity due to the element type selector div. To ensure that the .child class styles are applied, you need to make the .child selector more specific or use !important.
Here’s the updated CSS with increased specificity:
div.text {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
}

div.text.child {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 14px;
}

